# Не проходит https запрос. SSL handshake failed

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, https, openssl, wget

У партнеров есть АПИ, доступ к которому раньше осуществлялся по https, но несколько дней назад запросы к нему перестали проходить, при этом никаких работ на сервере не проводилось.

Сервер на  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Вот что получается при попытке получить доступ через wget

```
wget https://31.00.000.51  --debug
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.19.4 on linux-gnu.

Reading HSTS entries from /root/.wget-hsts
URI encoding = ‘UTF-8’
Converted file name 'index.html' (UTF-8) -> 'index.html' (UTF-8)
--2020-02-26 05:59:48--  https://31.00.000.51/
Connecting to 31.00.000.51:443... connected.
Created socket 5.
Releasing 0x000055a2d6738db0 (new refcount 0).
Deleting unused 0x000055a2d6738db0.
Initiating SSL handshake.
SSL handshake failed.
Closed fd 5
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

А вот что при попытке подключиться через openssl

```
openssl s_client -connect  31.00.000.51:443 
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 314 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

Я пробывал задавать разные версии tls в параметрах, но не помогло. 
Также стоит отметить следующее:

- Запросы по http проходят успешно
- Запросы на другие сервера c https тоже проходят успешно
- Запросы на проблемный сервер с другого сервера также проходят успешно

Т.е проблема с соединением именно между двумя этими конкретными серверами
Блокировку ip адреса я отбросил, так как http работает успешно. curl тоже запросы не отправляет.

Comment: Если все ранее работало, то, возможно в вашем взаимодействии принимал участие клиентский серт, который либо заексаайрился, либо его отозвали?

Comment: Нет, с другого сервера запросы проходят нормально, на сертификаты не жалуется, если я Вас правильно понял конечно